# Is something happening with the ISP market in UK?

Tags: isp, adsl

We're being forced to look at rather expensive leased lines due to our distance from the exchange. Even on the new ADSL2+, we can't get much more than 3MBit/s but more importantly, we need to improve our upload speed.

Several vendors have offered us special deals if we sign up for three years before the end of October.

Call us cynical, but is something about to be launched in the UK that means leased lines will either be much lower price or under threat from other technologies. I assume that it could be ADSL2+ itself - if that's the case, we're still stuck :-(

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 1):

October is a half-year for a lot of corporations, so it might just be salesmen trying to hit targets.

Comment: Could be you've got it in one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

BT is in the process of rolling out its "[21st Century Network](http://www.btplc.com/21CN/)" - it *might* be the case that the wholesale price is expected to drop imminently in your area; as others hav said, it should also just be a case of sales targets.

Comment: As long as it's not come new leased-line competitor technology just about to be rolled out.

Comment: From what little I know, 21CN offers products that effectively make leased lines obsolete. Things like Ethernet extenders, which for us were cheaper than a leased line.

Answer (score 0):

Virgin/(NTL cough!) are talking about 100mBits to the door over their fibre optic network? not sure what the upload speed is.

Comment: ....if only I could receive their service, even thought they send me fliers saying I can...

Comment: VM is one of these companies offering a very good deal at the moment.